# How to save file in crontab using Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, cron, nano

I am editing a `crontab` file using the nano editor on Ubuntu.  I need to save my text as a `crontab` file.  When I attempt to save the file, it is asking me for the file name, but after I give the file name it's not taking or I'm not giving the proper path or something.  I have included a screen shot below.

[image]

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to do as follow:
Use [VI](http://www.vim.org/) as editor:

```
export VISUAL=vi
crontab -e
```

press **i** for write; than press `ESC` and `:wq` for save and exit.

Comment: @ teoreda : I did as per you i think it saved.Can you please tell me how can i check again that saved file.I need command.

Comment: its i think `crontab -l`.

Comment: Ok..Thnaks any ways.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily export the crontab for any user to a file:

```
crontab -u myuser -l > crontab.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

step1 : press Crl+X
step2 : press Ship+Y
step3 : press Enter key